# I am making dependent

Tags: meaning

*If I were to join the Communist Party someday (**something that, in turn, I am making dependent on one last twist of fate**), my stance would be to behave always radically and never logically when it came to the most important things.*

<sup>Source: [The Correspondence of Walter Benjamin, 1910-1940](https://books.google.com/books?id=57wpL-kZkMIC&pg=PA300&dq=%22making%20dependent%20on%20one%20last%20twist%20of%20fate%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjFrcOT1uvKAhUEuBQKHWSlBvYQ6AEIITAB)</sup>

Could you please clarify to me the passage in the brackets in the above sentence. Roughly I understand it that his joining the CP is not fully in his hands and that the higher instance will decide. Is "to be making dependent" an idiomatic expression?

Comment: It makes no clear sense.  **in turn** seems to come out of the blue, and it's not clear what particular "last twist of fate" he's alluding to. But he's setting it up as the determining condition.

Comment: No, "making (something) dependent" is not an idiom. ["Dependent" just means "decided or controlled by something else"](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/dependent), so the author is just saying "I am making this thing decided by something else."  (I think the whole sentence is pretty badly written, by the way.)

Comment: Could you be please more specific. What's wrong with that sentence? Is it grammar, style or something else?

Comment: It's the style, for me.  The author has put in a longish parenthetical statement that doesn't even make a lot of sense.  Why "in turn"?  What's the twist of fate he's referring to?  And then he says "...to behave always radically" which sounds clumsier than "to always behave radically".  For that matter, why does he say "my stance would be" instead of just "I would", unless maybe he's referring to a policy platform?  Maybe the whole paragraph would make it clearer, but I find the author's style unnecessarily prolix.

Comment: Perhaps the style has been constructed purposefully to convey the feeling that the person who is saying it is unbalanced.  At least, the tone and style of the sentence, then, would reflect the crazy meaning of it.

Comment: **in turn** (Ger. *wiederum*), should probably be rendered here as  "I repeat", as in: "If I ever were to join the Communist Party (something which, I repeat, has about as much chance of happening as a snowball in hell), I would always act radically, not logically, in the most important matters."    I repeat, or "again".

Comment: The original order is closer to this:  "I would always act radically, not logically, in the most important matters if I ever were to join the Communist Party (something which,again, has about as much chance of happening as a snowball in hell)."

Comment: @TRomano: I (somewhat resignedly) agreed with your first comment re *in turn* being either rather odd phrasing or heavily dependent on some earlier context that we don't have. But I can (much more enthusiastically) endorse your *later* comments, where I think you've totally nailed it.

Answer (score 1):

First, it should be noted that the author, Walter Benjamin, is writing a letter in **German**, translated to English. Although his style is refined, an editor would probably remove *in turn* from the parenthetical, leaving us with:

> "something I am making dependent on one last twist of fate"

While it is Benjamin's choice to join the Communist Party or not, he has made the decision conditional on the "twist of fate". That is, he has voluntarily decided to let "fate" make his choice for him.